# PDF conversion to CSV R

Tags: r, csv, pdf, pdftools, tabulizer

I am trying to load the following PDF into R, and convert the table into a CSV file.

I have tried both the library(pdftools) and library(tabulizer), & I have spent an afternoon going through various forums, but I do not seem to find an answer that works for me. I can load the PDF to R using the following code

```
x <- pdf_text("~/Desktop/PlantTraitAsia.pdf")
```

It uploads just fine, but it is not at all a table of table I can work with.

Here is a link to the PDF file:

http://vege1.kan.ynu.ac.jp/traits/PlantTraitAsia.pdf

I would simply like to upload the table into R, keep the header, and be able to export it to a TXT, CSV, or XLS file.

Thanks for your help

Comment: In fact, `x` in you "example" — specifically `x[2:34]` — contains some very usable data, you just wanted magic to happen vs parse fixed-width lines. And, given what David showed for `tabulizer` I'm finding it difficult to invest in the veracity of your claim of having tried it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.  And I know from what I wrote I get something useable, but not enough to a point where I know how to handle the dataset. Also, I did spend a lot of time on this, hours going through forums, and because I just couldn't get it to work, I felt it was best for me to ask.  I did not mean for it to come off as "do the work for me", it was/is a genuine question on my behalf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works well on my machine:

```
zz <- tabulizer::extract_tables("http://vege1.kan.ynu.ac.jp/traits/PlantTraitAsia.pdf", pages = 2)
head(zz[[1]])
```

This produces:

```
     [,1]  [,2]                      [,3]                    
[1,] "ID"  "Category\rof\rpermissio" "Species"               
[2,] "83"  "A"                       "Abies mariesii Masters"
[3,] "155" "A"                       "Abies mariesii Masters"
[4,] "225" "A"                       "Abies mariesii Masters"
[5,] "297" "A"                       "Abies mariesii Masters"
[6,] "369" "A"                       "Abies mariesii Masters"
     [,4]                                                                            [,5]         [,6]   
[1,] "Traits"                                                                        "Value"      "Notes"
[2,] "Maximum heighyt (m)"                                                           "18.17"      ""     
[3,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative\rlight intensity, %), Anderson\r1964. J. Ecol." "1.15"       ""     
[4,] "Length of fruit (mm)"                                                          "8"          ""     
[5,] "Pollination mode"                                                              "Anemophily" ""     
[6,] "Type of fruit"                                                                 "Wing-hair"  ""
```

To get only headers (first line of your table):

```
zz[[1]][1,]
```

Comment: Hi @David.  Interestingly, I also have tried a code like this one from a previous forum, and I get an error when using the function extract_tables.

I only open the library(tabulizer) before trying the code, should I open any other library? 

here is the error I get:

Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Integer.compare(II)I

And I tried loading the PDF directly from my machine, and get the same error.

Comment: OK, it means you have an issue with rJava which is needed by `tabulizer`. Have a search on SO about rJava and installation, you should find a solution

Comment: Hello @David.  I got rJava to work on my mac, yet I still get the same error as posted above.  I have spent a considerable amount of time on this, I will try it on a PC at work to see if it works on PC and just not on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach based on the R package RDCOMClient

```
library(RDCOMClient)

####################################################################
#### Step 1 : We use the OCR of Word to convert the PDF to Word ####
####################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- 0
path_To_PDF_File <- "C:\\PlantTraitAsia.pdf"
path_To_Word_File <- "C:\\PlantTraitAsia.docx"

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_PDF_File),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_To_Word_File)

###############################################################
#### Step 2 : We extract the tables from the word document ####
###############################################################
nb_Tables <- doc$tables()$count()
list_Table <- list()

for(l in 1 : nb_Tables)
{
  print(l)
  nb_Row <- doc$tables(l)$Rows()$Count()
  nb_Col <- doc$tables(l)$Columns()$Count()
  mat_Temp <- matrix(NA, nrow = nb_Row, ncol = nb_Col)
  
  for(i in 1 : nb_Row)
  {
    for(j in 1 : nb_Col)
    {
      mat_Temp[i, j] <- doc$tables(l)$cell(i, j)$range()$text()
    }
  }
  
  list_Table[[l]] <- mat_Temp
}

final_Mat <- do.call("rbind", list_Table)
final_Mat[, 1 : 4]
```

We obtain the following matrix

```
[,1]      [,2]                        [,3]                                                                                   
  [1,] "ID\r\a"  "Category of permissio\r\a" "Species\r\a"                                                                          
  [2,] "83\r\a"  "A\r\a"                     "Abies mariesii Masters\r\a"                                                           
  [3,] "155\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Abies mariesii Masters\r\a"                                                           
  [4,] "225\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Abies mariesii Masters\r\a"                                                           
  [5,] "297\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Abies mariesii Masters\r\a"                                                           
  [6,] "369\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Abies mariesii Masters\r\a"                                                           
  [7,] "706\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Abies sachalinensis (Schmidt) Masters\r\a"                                            
  [8,] "750\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Abies sachalinensis (Schmidt) Masters\r\a"                                            
  [9,] "794\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Abies sachalinensis (Schmidt) Masters\r\a"                                            
 [10,] "837\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Abies sachalinensis (Schmidt) Masters\r\a"                                            
 [11,] "881\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Abies sachalinensis (Schmidt) Masters\r\a"                                            
 [12,] "6\r\a"   "A\r\a"                     "Abies spectabilis (D. Don) Mirbel\r\a"                                                
 [13,] "10\r\a"  "A\r\a"                     "Abies spectabilis (D. Don) Mirbel\r\a"                                                
 [14,] "82\r\a"  "A\r\a"                     "Abies veitchii Lindley\r\a"                                                           
 [15,] "154\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Abies veitchii Lindley\r\a"                                                           
 [16,] "224\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Abies veitchii Lindley\r\a"                                                           
 [17,] "296\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Abies veitchii Lindley\r\a"                                                           
 [18,] "368\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Abies veitchii Lindley\r\a"                                                           
 [19,] "707\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acanthopanax senticosus (Rupr. et Maxim.) Harms.\r\a"                                 
 [20,] "751\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acanthopanax senticosus (Rupr. et Maxim.) Harms.\r\a"                                 
 [21,] "795\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acanthopanax senticosus (Rupr. et Maxim.) Harms.\r\a"                                 
 [22,] "838\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acanthopanax senticosus (Rupr. et Maxim.) Harms.\r\a"                                 
 [23,] "882\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acanthopanax senticosus (Rupr. et Maxim.) Harms.\r\a"                                 
 [24,] "708\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acer japonicum Thunb.\r\a"                                                            
 [25,] "752\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acer japonicum Thunb.\r\a"                                                            
 [26,] "796\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acer japonicum Thunb.\r\a"                                                            
 [27,] "839\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acer japonicum Thunb.\r\a"                                                            
 [28,] "883\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acer japonicum Thunb.\r\a"                                                            
 [29,] "97\r\a"  "A\r\a"                     "Acer micranthum Sieb. et Zucc.\r\a"                                                   
 [30,] "169\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer micranthum Sieb. et Zucc.\r\a"                                                   
 [31,] "239\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer micranthum Sieb. et Zucc.\r\a"                                                   
 [32,] "311\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer micranthum Sieb. et Zucc.\r\a"                                                   
 [33,] "383\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer micranthum Sieb. et Zucc.\r\a"                                                   
 [34,] "99\r\a"  "A\r\a"                     "Acer mono var. mayrii Sugimoto\r\a"                                                   
 [35,] "171\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer mono var. mayrii Sugimoto\r\a"                                                   
 [36,] "241\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer mono var. mayrii Sugimoto\r\a"                                                   
 [37,] "313\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer mono var. mayrii Sugimoto\r\a"                                                   
 [38,] "385\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer mono var. mayrii Sugimoto\r\a"                                                   
 [39,] "130\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer morifolium Koidz.\r\a"                                                           
 [40,] "200\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer morifolium Koidz.\r\a"                                                           
 [41,] "272\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer morifolium Koidz.\r\a"                                                           
 [42,] "344\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer morifolium Koidz.\r\a"                                                           
 [43,] "416\r\a" "A\r\a"                     "Acer morifolium Koidz.\r\a"                                                           
 [44,] "472\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acer morifolium Koidz.\r\a"                                                           
 [45,] "522\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acer morifolium Koidz.\r\a"                                                           
 [46,] "662\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Acer morifolium Koidz.\r\a"                                                           
 [47,] "709\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actaea asiatica Hara.\r\a"                                                            
 [48,] "753\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actaea asiatica Hara.\r\a"                                                            
 [49,] "797\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actaea asiatica Hara.\r\a"                                                            
 [50,] "840\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actaea asiatica Hara.\r\a"                                                            
 [51,] "884\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actaea asiatica Hara.\r\a"                                                            
 [52,] "710\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actinidia arguta (Sieb. et Zucc.) Planch. ex Miq.\r\a"                                
 [53,] "754\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actinidia arguta (Sieb. et Zucc.) Planch. ex Miq.\r\a"                                
 [54,] "798\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actinidia arguta (Sieb. et Zucc.) Planch. ex Miq.\r\a"                                
 [55,] "841\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actinidia arguta (Sieb. et Zucc.) Planch. ex Miq.\r\a"                                
 [56,] "885\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Actinidia arguta (Sieb. et Zucc.) Planch. ex Miq.\r\a"                                
 [57,] "51\r\a"  "A\r\a"                     "Alangium javanicum\r\a"                                                               
 [58,] "473\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Aleurites cordata (thunb.) R. Br. ex Steudel.\r\a"                                    
 [59,] "523\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Aleurites cordata (thunb.) R. Br. ex Steudel.\r\a"                                    
 [60,] "580\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Aleurites cordata (thunb.) R. Br. ex Steudel.\r\a"                                    
 [61,] "622\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Aleurites cordata (thunb.) R. Br. ex Steudel.\r\a"                                    
 [62,] "663\r\a" "B\r\a"                     "Aleurites cordata (thunb.) R. Br. ex Steudel.\r\a"                                    
       [,4]                                                                                                                      [,5]                             [,6]       
  [1,] "Traits\r\a"                                                                                                              "Value\r\a"                      "Notes\r\a"
  [2,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "18.17\r\a"                      "\r\a"     
  [3,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "1.15\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
  [4,] "Length of fruit (mm)\r\a"                                                                                                "8\r\a"                          "\r\a"     
  [5,] "Pollination mode\r\a"                                                                                                    "Anemophily\r\a"                 "\r\a"     
  [6,] "Type of fruit\r\a"                                                                                                       "Wing-hair\r\a"                  "\r\a"     
  [7,] "Stem type\r\a"                                                                                                           "Woody\r\a"                      "\r\a"     
  [8,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "3.816887653\r\a"                "\r\a"     
  [9,] "Maximum height (m)\r\a"                                                                                                  "24.7\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [10,] "Vegetative spread distance (m)\r\a"                                                                                      "0\r\a"                          "\r\a"     
 [11,] "Vegetative reproduction\r\a"                                                                                             "None\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [12,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "24\r\a"                         "\r\a"     
 [13,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "45.7\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [14,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "18\r\a"                         "\r\a"     
 [15,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "1.57\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [16,] "Length of fruit (mm)\r\a"                                                                                                "6\r\a"                          "\r\a"     
 [17,] "Pollination mode\r\a"                                                                                                    "Anemophily\r\a"                 "\r\a"     
 [18,] "Type of fruit\r\a"                                                                                                       "Wing-hair\r\a"                  "\r\a"     
 [19,] "Stem type\r\a"                                                                                                           "Woody\r\a"                      "\r\a"     
 [20,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "5.629993917\r\a"                "\r\a"     
 [21,] "Maximum height (m)\r\a"                                                                                                  "1.5\r\a"                        "\r\a"     
 [22,] "Vegetative spread distance (m)\r\a"                                                                                      "1\r\a"                          "\r\a"     
 [23,] "Vegetative reproduction\r\a"                                                                                             "Rhyzome\r\a"                    "\r\a"     
 [24,] "Stem type\r\a"                                                                                                           "Woody\r\a"                      "\r\a"     
 [25,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "5.870242245\r\a"                "\r\a"     
 [26,] "Maximum height (m)\r\a"                                                                                                  "12.1\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [27,] "Vegetative spread distance (m)\r\a"                                                                                      "0\r\a"                          "\r\a"     
 [28,] "Vegetative reproduction\r\a"                                                                                             "Sprout at the base of stem\r\a" "\r\a"     
 [29,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "9.2\r\a"                        "\r\a"     
 [30,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "8.86\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [31,] "Length of fruit (mm)\r\a"                                                                                                "15\r\a"                         "\r\a"     
 [32,] "Pollination mode\r\a"                                                                                                    "Entomophily\r\a"                "\r\a"     
 [33,] "Type of fruit\r\a"                                                                                                       "Wing-hair\r\a"                  "\r\a"     
 [34,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "18.3\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [35,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "7.24\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [36,] "Length of fruit (mm)\r\a"                                                                                                "23\r\a"                         "\r\a"     
 [37,] "Pollination mode\r\a"                                                                                                    "Entomophily\r\a"                "\r\a"     
 [38,] "Type of fruit\r\a"                                                                                                       "Wing-hair\r\a"                  "\r\a"     
 [39,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "13.5\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [40,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "27.05059776\r\a"                "\r\a"     
 [41,] "Length of fruit (mm)\r\a"                                                                                                "15\r\a"                         "\r\a"     
 [42,] "Pollination mode\r\a"                                                                                                    "Entomophily\r\a"                "\r\a"     
 [43,] "Type of fruit\r\a"                                                                                                       "Wing-hair\r\a"                  "\r\a"     
 [44,] "Vegetative spread distance (m)\r\a"                                                                                      "0\r\a"                          "\r\a"     
 [45,] "Stem type\r\a"                                                                                                           "Woody\r\a"                      "\r\a"     
 [46,] "Vegetative reproduction\r\a"                                                                                             "None\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [47,] "Stem type\r\a"                                                                                                           "Herbaceous\r\a"                 "\r\a"     
 [48,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "3.236520779\r\a"                "\r\a"     
 [49,] "Maximum height (m)\r\a"                                                                                                  "0.61\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [50,] "Vegetative spread distance (m)\r\a"                                                                                      "0\r\a"                          "\r\a"     
 [51,] "Vegetative reproduction\r\a"                                                                                             "Sprout at the base of stem\r\a" "\r\a"     
 [52,] "Stem type\r\a"                                                                                                           "Liana\r\a"                      "\r\a"     
 [53,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "5.547807614\r\a"                "\r\a"     
 [54,] "Maximum height (m)\r\a"                                                                                                  "16.3\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [55,] "Vegetative spread distance (m)\r\a"                                                                                      "10\r\a"                         "\r\a"     
 [56,] "Vegetative reproduction\r\a"                                                                                             "Rooting from vine\r\a"          "\r\a"     
 [57,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "16.8\r\a"                       "\r\a"     
 [58,] "Vegetative spread distance (m)\r\a"                                                                                      "0\r\a"                          "\r\a"     
 [59,] "Stem type\r\a"                                                                                                           "Woody\r\a"                      "\r\a"     
 [60,] "Shade tolerance (min. relative light intensity, %), Anderson 1964. J. Ecol.\r\a"                                         "12.19244\r\a"                   "\r\a"     
 [61,] "Maximum heighyt (m)\r\a"                                                                                                 "9.7\r\a"                        "\r\a"     
 [62,] "Vegetative reproduction\r\a"                                                                                             "None\r\a"                       "\r\a"     

 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 863 rows ]
```